How to Maintain Continuous Execution of JavaScript Code in Google DevTools Regardless of Tab Activity?
I am attempting to run a continuous interval-based JavaScript function using Google DevTools on a specific webpage, even when the tab is not active. However, I've encountered issues where the interval execution rate changes or stops entirely when I switch to another tab.
I've already added the website URL to Chrome's performance settings (chrome://settings/performance > "Always keep these sites active"), which theoretically should maintain the tab's activity. Despite this setting, the JavaScript interval still behaves inconsistently.
Here's a simplified version of the code I'm using:
let lastTime = new Date();

const pingInterval = setInterval(() => {
    const secs = ((new Date()).getTime() - lastTime.getTime()) / 1000;
    if (secs > 2)
        console.error('ALERT', secs);
    else
        console.log(secs);

    lastTime = new Date();
}, 1000);

The expected behavior is for this interval to execute every second consistently, regardless of whether the tab is active or not. However, the interval timing changes automatically to longer intervals (e.g., 1 minute) or stops entirely after a few minutes of inactivity. Check the image below for reference:

How can I ensure that this JavaScript interval continues to run at the specified frequency (e.g., every 1 second) without being affected by tab activity or inactivity?
